# How to properly plot collection of polygons (stl file)?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, mayavi.mlab

I have stl file and numpy-stl library. By it own, mesh class have *.x, .y, .z* properties, which can be plotted

```
my_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(file)
x = my_mesh.x
y = my_mesh.y
z = my_mesh.z
mlab.points3d(x, y, z)
mlab.show()
```

The result is slow and pretty bad visually

[image: plot]

Also mesh have *vectors* property but I have no idea how to work with it.
In matplotlib I can use:

```
figure = plt.figure()
axes = mplot3d.Axes3D(figure)
axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(my_mesh.vectors))
plt.show()
```

The result

[image: img]

Is working property but terribly slow and pretty much unusable.

**Is there a better ways to plot this?**

Comment: are you just trying to visualize? or plot? you could try vtk or this vtk plotting pkg someone whipped up: https://github.com/bwoodsend/vtkplotlib

Comment: STL is set of triangles design for litography so the triangulated mesh have usually **a lot** of triangles so how much triangles you really have? few `100 000` is OK but if you got millions or more you hitting the gfx bandwith. On top of that you're using python which is slow on its own ... I do not use python but I would try some lib/package (written in C++) that uses OpenGL or DX to accelerate your rendering into VAO or something so your mesh would be stored at GPU instead of copying each frame from CPU to GPU ... how big is the STL file? is it ASCII or binary ? what gfx card you got ?

Comment: @Spektre almost 100,000 triangles or ~5mb
I use mayavi which is build on top of vtk. And vtk consists of a C++ class library.

Comment: 100K triangles should be OK on PC but you should make sure you load the model into your lib just once and not on per frame basis ... I do not know vtk but if it is not HW accelerated you're out of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy-stl library loads stl file as numpy array. 'Vectors' attribute is Nx3x3 numpy array. To put it simply this array is collection of faces of the shape. So N stands for number of faces, 3 is number of point to define face of the figure and final dimension represent point coordinates in 3d space.

In most libraries to plot 3d shape you need to define two things - coordinates of the points and indexes of the points to draw faces of figure.

numpy-stl simplifies process because all points are unique and in order. That means that index of points to define face is just index in vertex array.

Also it worth mentioning that you need to define not points itself but x, y, z separately. Same counts for the faces.

Based on that we cold write this. I choose plotly because it fast and interactive

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from stl import mesh  # numpy-stl
import numpy as np

data = mesh.Mesh.from_file('fabric.stl')

points = data.vectors.reshape(-1,3)  # reshape Nx3x3 to N*3x3 to convert polygons to points
faces_index = np.arange(len(points))  # get indexes of points

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Mesh3d(
        x = points[:,0],  # pass first column of points array
        y = points[:,1],  # .. second column
        z = points[:,2],  # .. third column
        # i, j and k give the vertices of triangles
        i = faces_index[0::3],  # indexes of the points. k::3 means pass every third element 
        j = faces_index[1::3],  # starting from k element
        k = faces_index[2::3],  # for example 2::3 in arange would be 2,5,8,...
        opacity = .9
    )
])

fig.show()
```

Which would display:
[image: plotly plot]

Image from default windows stl file view tool:
[image: windows plot]

Result look correct. Please ignore blue dot on the top of the plotly plot and holes near top ring, its the file artifacts and presented in both variants.

Answer (score 0):

Since vertices are used multiple times, it may be helpful to first find the unique points in the vector array. Here is an example using pandas to remove duplicates and define the triangles and open3d for visualization.

`df.drop_duplicates` removes the duplicate vertices, now we need to find the indices of the new vertex list based on the old one. I did this using pandas `merge`.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def extract_vertices_and_triangles(mesh_vertices):
    # Reshape the array to (n*3, 3)
    flat_vertices = mesh_vertices.reshape(-1, 3)

    # Create a DataFrame for easy manipulation
    df = pd.DataFrame(flat_vertices, columns=["x", "y", "z"])

    # Create a new DataFrame with unique vertices
    unique_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["x", "y", "z"]).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Create a mapping from old indices to unique indices
    merged_df = (
        df.reset_index()
        .merge(unique_df.reset_index(), on=["x", "y", "z"], how="right")
        .sort_values(by="index_x")
    )
    triangles = merged_df["index_y"].to_numpy()

    triangles = triangles.reshape(-1, 3)

    # Reshape the unique vertices to the original shape
    unique_vertices = unique_df[["x", "y", "z"]].values

    return unique_vertices, triangles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    armadillo_mesh = o3d.data.ArmadilloMesh()

    mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(armadillo_mesh.path)
    mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])

    vertices = np.array(mesh.vertices)
    triangles = np.array(mesh.triangles)

    np_vertices = vertices[triangles]

    vert, triangle = extract_vertices_and_triangles(np_vertices)

    # Create Open3D TriangleMesh
    mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh()
    mesh.vertices = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(vert)
    mesh.triangles = o3d.utility.Vector3iVector(triangle)
    mesh.compute_vertex_normals()

    # Visualize the extracted mesh
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])
```